# Good rational approximations using continued fractions?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

My textbook claims that the best rational approximations (relative the size of the numerator and denominator) of an irrational number by using continued fraction are those whose expansions are terminated after a relatively large number.

Concretely, we know that $\pi = [3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, \ldots]$

So my textbook claims that good approximations would be
\begin{align*}
  x_5 & = [3, 7, 15, 1, 292] =  \frac{103993}{33102} & |\pi - x_5| = 5.78\cdot 10^{-10}\\
  x_{13} & = [3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14] = \frac{80143857}{25510582} & |\pi - x_{13}| = 5.79\cdot 10^{-16} 
\end{align*}

But isn't it just the case that 
\begin{align*}
  x_4 & = [3, 7, 15, 1] =  \frac{355}{113} & |\pi - x_4| = 2.67\cdot 10^{-7}\\
  x_{12} & = [3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1] = \frac{5419351}{1725033} & |\pi - x_{12}| = 2.21\cdot 10^{-14} 
\end{align*}
are also pretty good relative to the size of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Actually, if the *next* term in the continued fraction for $r$ is $n$, then $\frac1{n+2}\le q^2\left|\frac pq-r\right|\le\frac1n$. Thus, the approximant gotten by truncating the continued fraction for $r$ just before a large term is good in the sense that $q^2\left|\frac pq-r\right|$ is small. For example, $113^2\left|\frac{355}{113}-\pi\right|=\frac1{293.572643}$.

Answer (score 0):

The CFEs are the [best rational approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) to a number in the sense that if $\frac pq\in\mathbb Q$ is a convergent of $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ then
$$\left|\frac pq - x\right| = \min_{p'\in\mathbb Z, 1\le q'\le q} \left|\frac{p'}{q'} - x\right|$$
So yes, *all convergents are good approximations*.